# Python - Need to use the python packages without installing using pip/command prompt

Tags: python, package

I am trying to install a python package but I'm not able to install using Pip/Command prompt because I'm having user access at work where I'm not able to open the command prompt. so I can't install anything using pip/conda.

I can able to download the package from GitHub. Is there any option from here to use the package in the python package in your own program?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `setup.py` file when you download the package. You can run the following command to install it.

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I'm not able to open the command prompt due to office restrictions.

Comment: what about using editor like pycharm? They have a build in package manager.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html